# Android Gradle Build Error With Parse SDK

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add the Parse SDK library to my android build but I receive the following error when I try to run my project:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.>
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

I have tried enabling multiDex which has not worked.

My gradle build is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.green.philip.budgetplannerdroid"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate entry using Parse and Multidex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140704/duplicate-entry-using-parse-and-multidex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue depends by

```
  compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
```

This library has a [dependency](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/parse/parse-android/1.12.0/parse-android-1.12.0.pom) with `com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0` while `com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0` has a [dependency](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.4.0/bolts-android-1.4.0.pom) with `com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0`.
It means that you are including the same library but with different versions.

Use:

```
compile ('com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'){
     exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-tasks';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'