# I want make android chat application and facing following Error:

Tags: android

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryControlle

And

My Gradle.build Like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    dexOptions {
        // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "myfirstapp.sohail.smartchat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])    
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'    
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'

    compile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.2'    
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'   
}
```

Comment: Anything in the `libs/` folder related to parse? If so, remove it

Comment: see this topic [Duplicate entry using Parse and Multidex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140704/duplicate-entry-using-parse-and-multidex)

Answer (score 0):

`parceinceptors` needs to be on `debugCompile` not `compile` in `dependency` block

see: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseInterceptors-Android